# Aggregating Attributes

Tags: query, oracle-12c, pivot

I have a product review table in an oracle 12.1 EE database that has different attributes rated on a scale of 1 through 5. How do I query this table to count up all of the reviews and group by the product and the 1-5 rating.

**Example Data**

```sql
WITH DATA_SET
AS
    (   SELECT  1   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                5   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                5   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'b' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                5   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                5   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                3   AS OVERALL,
                2   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                2   AS OVERALL,
                1   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                1   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    DATA_SET;

review_id | product_id | overall | comfort | fit   | appearance
----------------------------------------------------------------
1            a            5         4         5       4
2            a            4         4         4       4
3            b            4         5         4       5
4            c            3         2         2       4
5            c            2         1         2       1
```

I've looked at doing pivots and various analytic queries. But I can't quite get the desired output below. I'm sure I'm making this too hard. But for the life of me I can't put this together. Any help/direction would be appreciated!

**Example Output**

```
product_id | rating | overall | comfort | fit   | appearance
--------------------------------------------------------------
a            1         0        0         0         0
a            2         0        0         0         0
a            3         0        0         0         0
a            4         1        2         1         2
a            5         1        0         1         0
b            1         0        0         0         0
b            2         0        0         0         0
b            3         0        0         0         0
b            4         1        0         1         1
b            5         0        1         0         0
c            1         0        1         0         1
c            2         1        1         2         0
c            3         1        0         0         0
c            4         0        0         0         1
c            5         0        0         0         0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## HOWTO

Your query needs to do the following:

1. `UNPIVOT` the data
2. `PIVOT` the data to get the `COUNT()`
3. add missing rows

   - sub-query of all row `LEFT OUTER JOIN` calculated data
   - use of then not-well-known `MODEL` clause
4. and, of course, the `ORDER BY` clause

## EXAMPLE 1 (sub-query)

```sql
WITH DATA_SET
AS
    (   SELECT  1   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                5   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                5   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'b' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                5   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                5   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                3   AS OVERALL,
                2   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                2   AS OVERALL,
                1   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                1   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
    )
,unpivot_data as (
  SELECT  product_id, score, catagory
  FROM    DATA_SET
    UNPIVOT ( score
              for catagory in (
                overall, comfort, fit, appearance
              )
            )
  )
,count_values as (  
  select product_id, score, overall, comfort, fit, appearance
  from unpivot_data
  pivot (
    count(catagory)
    for catagory in ( 'OVERALL' AS overall, 'COMFORT' as comfort, 'FIT' as fit, 'APPEARANCE' as appearance)
  )
)
,all_rows as (
  select *
  from (select distinct product_id from data_set),
       (select level as score from dual connect by level <= 5)
)
select a.product_id, a.product_id
  ,nvl( b.overall, 0) overall
  ,nvl( b.comfort, 0) comfort
  ,nvl( b.fit, 0) fit
  ,nvl( b.appearance, 0) appearance
from all_rows a
  left outer join count_values b
    on (a.product_id=b.product_id and a.score=b.score)
order by a.product_id, a.score
```

## EXAMPLE 2 (model)

```sql
WITH DATA_SET
AS
    (   SELECT  1   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                5   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                5   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'a' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                4   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'b' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                4   AS OVERALL,
                5   AS COMFORT,
                4   AS FIT,
                5   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                3   AS OVERALL,
                2   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                4   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5   AS REVIEW_ID,
                'c' AS PRODUCT_ID,
                2   AS OVERALL,
                1   AS COMFORT,
                2   AS FIT,
                1   AS APPEARANCE
        FROM    DUAL
    )
,unpivot_data as (
  SELECT  product_id, score, catagory
  FROM    DATA_SET
    UNPIVOT ( score
              for catagory in (
                overall, comfort, fit, appearance
              )
            )
  )
,count_values as (  
  select product_id, score, overall, comfort, fit, appearance
  from unpivot_data
  pivot (
    count(catagory)
    for catagory in ( 'OVERALL' AS overall, 'COMFORT' as comfort, 'FIT' as fit, 'APPEARANCE' as appearance)
  )
)
select *
from count_values
model return all rows
  DIMENSION by (product_id,score)
  measures ( overall, comfort, fit, appearance )
  rules (
    overall[ for product_id in ( select distinct product_id from data_set), for score in (1,2,3,4,5)] =
      nvl( overall[ cv(product_id), cv(score) ], 0),
    comfort[ for product_id in (select distinct product_id from data_set), for score in (1,2,3,4,5)] =
      nvl( comfort[ cv(product_id), cv(score) ], 0),
    fit[ for product_id in (select distinct product_id from data_set), for score in (1,2,3,4,5)] =
      nvl( fit[ cv(product_id), cv(score) ], 0),
    appearance[ for product_id in (select distinct product_id from data_set), for score in (1,2,3,4,5)] =
      nvl( appearance[ cv(product_id), cv(score) ], 0)
    )
order by product_id, score
```

Comment: This is beautiful stuff! I was definitely missing the unpivot in my trials. Also, you are spot on about the model clause. I've never seen it and it looks kind of awesome. Thanks for bringing that to my attention. Also, one note about your sub-query solution, you have: select a.product_id, a.product_id. I assume that is supposed to be select a.product_id, a.score?